# Killed Rails on my machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, terminal, rvm

Not sure what I have done but I can't get rails server to work or any other rails call. Here's my terminal output, does anyone have any ideas how I can fix this please?

```
Ryans-MacBook-Pro:wozzoncornwall ryanberry$ rails -v
/Users/ryanberry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require': dlopen(/Users/ryanberry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.2/digest/sha1.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: @@HOMEBREW_CELLAR@@/openssl/1.0.1g/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Reason: image not found - /Users/ryanberry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.2/digest/sha1.bundle
    from /Users/ryanberry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
    from /Users/ryanberry/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ryanberry/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:148:in `definition'
    from /Users/ryanberry/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:116:in `setup'
    from /Users/ryanberry/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ryanberry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:116:in `require'
    from /Users/ryanberry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:116:in `rescue in require'
    from /Users/ryanberry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:122:in `require'
    from /Users/ryanberry/wozzoncornwall/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ryanberry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
    from /Users/ryanberry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
    from script/rails:5:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Update openssl lately to mitigate for heartbleed?

Comment: I think you should try to re-install your `openssl` library...

Comment: I'm with @UriAgassi ... re-install openssl.

Comment: Thanks both, how do I do this?

Comment: Should I just use homebrew like the answer given here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126830/how-to-upgrade-openssl-in-os-x

Comment: Tried that anyway and it worked :-) Thanks again.